# Superimpose multiple images

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, images, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have multiple pictures that are look alike, they're all black and differ only in the one dot of the screen, I want to combine them in one picture so I can see all the dots in one picture. How can I do this using something like ImageMagic? I don't want to use something with gui bc there are a lot of pictures, but they're not that big, so it would be easier to do this with terminal utility. I tried

```
composite -blend 50 *.png res.png
```

but it didn't work out.

UPD: Now I understood that it doesn't work because it works only with two images, how do I do these to all the images that matches the regular expression like somth*.png?

Comment: "didn't work" is a poor description. All it conveys is you could not achieve your goal. Please describe precisely what happens when you try that command.

Comment: It shows only the last dot, I guess, and not the others, at least I can't see them

Comment: Is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/329886 of any help?

Comment: Not really, because it's not the problem to do many files, the main problem is how to overlay them correctly

Comment: for blending, is there a logic function available, such as OR or AND? ... perhaps, convert black to transparent

Comment: Okay, thanks, I didn't know that, but now I see that composite works only with 2 pictures...Will try to do with more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [Screen compositing method](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#screen).

Since the composition only accepts two input files at a time, loop over all the input files.

Substitute `somth1.png` below by any of the input files. It is needed because `res.png` is always a starting point.

```bsh
cp somth1.png res.png 
for f in somth*.png;
    do composite -compose Screen "$f" res.png res.png
done
```